# How to add variables {{first name}} to the tiptap editor(React)

Tags: reactjs, frontend, tiptap

How to add variables {{first name}} to the tiptap editor(React)

and the UI should be look like this.

How can I achieve this in the Tiptap editor

I tried with @Tiptap/React package and it's not working with mention one.

I have attached an image file.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.